# select td elemensts with colspan

Tags: jquery, dom

How can I get all td elements with 'colspan' greater than 1 in jQuery?

```
var nodes = $('td[colspan>1]');
```

The code above seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there is no colspan=0 you can just do

```
$('td[colspan]').not('[colspan=1]')
```

Comment: What if a td has no colspan at all? <td>test</td>

Comment: because of the `[colspan]` they will not be included.

Comment: I made an edit to improve performance in modern browsers according to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Comment: It this cross-browser approach?

Comment: Yes, jQuery does all the cross browser stuff. In modern browsers it'll just run a little faster

Comment: I used this to do:  $('th[colspan]').not('[colspan=1]').addClass('center'). Works great!

Answer (score 7):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var nodes = $('td[colspan]').filter(function() {
  return +$(this).attr('colspan') > 1
});
```

The `+` prepended to `$(this).attr('colspan')` converts the string into a number

Comment: you could also use `return this.colSpan > 1`

Comment: yes, I were not sure about the camelcase syntax of the property :) (lately I'm not used to deal with tables)

Answer (score 2):

```
var tds = $('td')​​​.each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('colspan') > 1){
        return  $(this);
    }
})​
```